# how to access object via javascript and show marked up tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, internationalization

I want to access the message with tag

This one works well it successfully without tag

```js
var dict = {
  "configMigratedTo": {
        "message": "Migrated configuration to configurator: "
    }
}

function buildMessage(src,param){
   var message=dict[src] ? dict[src].message : src
    return message;
}

console.log(buildMessage("configMigratedTo"));
```

However, if message added  marked up tag

```
var dict = {
  "configMigratedTo": {
        "message": "<span style=\"color: red\">Migrated configuration to configurator: </span>"
    }
}
```

it will get your message:

```
"<span style=\"color: red\">Migrated configuration to configurator: </span>"
```

i want Migrated configuration to configurator: in red

not `"<span style=\"color: red\">Migrated configuration to configurator: </span>"` printed on html

```
  $("[i18n]").each(function () {
    switch (this.tagName.toLowerCase()) {
      case "input":
        $(this).val(buildMessage($(this).attr("i18n")));
        break;
      default:
        $(this).text(buildMessage($(this).attr("i18n")));
    }
  });
```

Comment: You want `Migrated configuration to configurator: in red` -- this entire string?

Comment: Right.................

Comment: You can't put html in the value of an input and have it render.  You'd have to style the input element.

Comment: You will want to use `$(this).html` instead of `$(this).text`

Comment: @Olian04  your answer perfectly solve the question

Comment: @12345GG Glad to hear it :)